# Write Vector V as linear Combination of U1, U2 and U3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a question in Schaum's series Linear Algebra [book](http://www.astronomia.edu.uy/progs/algebra/Linear_Algebra,_4th_Edition__(2009)Lipschutz-Lipson.pdf) on Vector chapter. Page 23. 1.49 problem.

[image]

The answer I get is

[image]

But the answer given is

[image]

which is

$$ x = 3, y = -1, z = 2 $$

Just need validation that I am correct. Thanks.

Comment: Try plugging in wolfram's solutions back into the equations. Do they work?

Comment: the given answer gives $\begin{bmatrix}9\\ \color{red}0 \\ 16 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the provided solution does not work, since the second coordinate is:
$$3 \cdot 3 - 5 +2 \cdot (-2) = 0 \neq -3.$$
I suspect this is a typo in the problem (the second coordinate of $v$ should be $0$, not $-3$).

Comment: Yes. That should be the case. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%2B+2y+%2B+4z+%3D+9%2C+3x+%2B+5y+-+2z+%3D+0%2C+3x+-+y+%2B+3z+%3D+16